# andere Verwendungen von "eines" außer im Genitiv

Tags: pronoun, article

Normalerweise wird es in Deutschkursen erklärt, dass "eines" nur für den Genitiv benutzt wird. Heute aber habe ich folgenden Satz gelesen:

"Nur eines scheint sich hier abzuzeichnen..."

Offenbar handelt es sich hier nicht um den Genitiv. "Eines" scheint eher "one thing" im Englischen zu entsprechen: "Only one thing seems to make itself apparent..."

Wie erklärt man aus grammatikalischer Sicht diese Verwendung? Warum schreibt man nicht "ein Ding", "eine Sache", oder vielleicht einfach "eins"?

Kann man dieses Wort problemlos auf andere Kontexte übertragen? z.B. Ich bin im Supermarkt vor der Kasse und es gibt einen Mann, der vor mir steht und ganz viele Sachen hat. Ich will nur einen Artikel kaufen und frage ihn, "Darf ich mich vordrängeln? Ich habe nur eines."

Comment: Ein Wörterbuch (z.B. das Wiktionary) scheint deine Frage zu beantworten

Answer (score 4):

Die angegebene Regel ist eine Vereinfachung, weil sie sich nur auf den unbestimmten Artikel bezieht.

Wie in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eines#Deklinierte_Form,_Numerale) nachzulesen kann es aber auch ein Indefinitpronomen sein, und im Singular Neutrum wird mit der starken Flexion sowohl im Nominativ als auch im Akkusativ *eines* daraus.

Zur Unterscheidung zu Zahlwörtern und dem unbestimmten Artikel gibt es einen Einstieg bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinitpronomen), besonders ergiebig ist die Seite allerdings nicht. Die Möglichkeit, auf ein unspezifisches Substantiv wie *Ding* oder *Sache* zu verzichten, finde ich am Indefinitpronomen attraktiv. Das wird auc gerne in der Wendung:

> Eines solltest du dir merken: ...

verwendet.

Im Supermarkt würde ich *eines* wahrscheinlich nicht verwenden, sondern *das* vorziehen.